# How to remove space before and after subsection?

Tags: subfloats, lncs

The following should be a complete example of my problem. Essentially for the first figure, there is a lot of space after the subsection that I would like to get rid of. Unfortunately, I cannot use any global commands that would modify the entire document because this is not recommended for the LNCS format. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks.

```
\documentclass{llncs}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[all,british]{foreign}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{wrapfig}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}
\section{Section}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas vitae nulla ac
eros sodales dictum eu sed orci. Fusce a nisi tortor. Donec quis ultricies odio,
at tempus purus. Ut vulputate gravida eleifend. Praesent bibendum ullamcorper
scelerisque. Suspendisse at nisl ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora
torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Donec odio ipsum, pharetra
a congue non, scelerisque vel leo. Curabitur ligula erat, feugiat sit amet eros
quis, accumsan facilisis libero. Pellentesque iaculis, velit id scelerisque
aliquam, tellus sem rutrum elit, sit amet elementum erat nisi imperdiet nunc. Ut
vitae neque molestie, tincidunt nibh et, sagittis orci.

\begin{figure}[H]
\subfloat[\label{fig:experiment1_normalized}Figure A]{
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{graphs/experiment1/experiment1a/normalized.eps}
}
\subfloat[\label{fig:experiment1_threads}Figure B $n=67\times 10^6$]{
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{graphs/experiment1/experiment1c/thread.eps}
}
\caption[]{\label{fig:experiment1_results} Fig A and B}
\end{figure}

\subsection{Subsection 1}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas vitae nulla ac
eros sodales dictum eu sed orci. Fusce a nisi tortor. Donec quis ultricies odio,
at tempus purus. Ut vulputate gravida eleifend. Praesent bibendum ullamcorper
scelerisque. Suspendisse at nisl ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora
torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Donec odio ipsum, pharetra
a congue non, scelerisque vel leo. Curabitur ligula erat, feugiat sit amet eros
quis, accumsan facilisis libero. Pellentesque iaculis, velit id scelerisque
aliquam, tellus sem rutrum elit, sit amet elementum erat nisi imperdiet nunc. Ut
vitae neque molestie, tincidunt nibh et, sagittis orci.

\begin{figure}[H]
\subfloat[\label{fig:experiment1_normalized}Figure A]{
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{graphs/experiment1/experiment1a/normalized.eps}
}
\subfloat[\label{fig:experiment1_threads}Figure B $n=67\times 10^6$]{
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{graphs/experiment1/experiment1c/thread.eps}
}
\caption[]{\label{fig:experiment1_results} Fig A and B}
\end{figure}

\subsection{Subsection 2}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas vitae nulla ac
eros sodales dictum eu sed orci. Fusce a nisi tortor. Donec quis ultricies odio,
at tempus purus. Ut vulputate gravida eleifend. Praesent bibendum ullamcorper
scelerisque. Suspendisse at nisl ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora
torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Donec odio ipsum, pharetra
a congue non, scelerisque vel leo. Curabitur ligula erat, feugiat sit amet eros
quis, accumsan facilisis libero. Pellentesque iaculis, velit id scelerisque
aliquam, tellus sem rutrum elit, sit amet elementum erat nisi imperdiet nunc. Ut
vitae neque molestie, tincidunt nibh et, sagittis orci.

\end{document}
```

Here is a picture of the problem:
[image]

Note the space between the subsection `Subsection 1` and the figure before as well as the text that follows. The reason the code includes two figures is that this problem somehow only manifests when I have another figure following. There is just something about this specific layout that causes that and I can't figure it out.

Comment: Avoid `[H]` and you'll be OK

Comment: `H` by design introduces large spaces (a it prevents latex moving the float to avoid having the space)